# AFNetworking 2 authentication with AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I want to use AFNetworking with a batch operation. I want to download 3 json files.

How to add basic authentication with AFHTTPRequestOperation ?

```
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *fileURL in filesToDownload) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest 
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                                initWithRequest:request];
    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation
                                                , id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
    }];
    [mutableOperations addObject:operation];
}

NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations 
                                    progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations
                                        , NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    NSLog(@"%d of %d complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");
}];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `AuthenticationChallengeBlock` to handle basic authentication challenge.

```
[operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:
        ^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
   NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential 
    credentialWithUser:@"username" 
    password:@"password" 
    persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

   [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}];
```

**Edit:**

Another option is to pass authentications in request header.

```
NSURLMutableRequest *request = [NSURLMutableRequest
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
NSData* authData = [[[NSString 
    stringWithFormat:@"username:password"] 
        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
            dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *finalAuth = [authData base64EncodedString];
finalAuth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",finalAuth];
[request setValue:finalAuth forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Yet another solution :

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential 
    credentialWithUser:@"login" 
    password:@"password" 
    persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

[operation setCredential:credential];
```

Comment: Thanks you, but `AuthenticationChallengeBlock` no longer exists in AFNeworking 2

Comment: Thanks it work.
I found an another solution :
    `NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential  credentialWithUser:_loginField.text password:_passwordField.text     persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [operation setCredential:credential];`

Comment: @mdespeuilles edit answer and add your solution. this will help some one else.