# How to set Authorization header in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

I was trying to implement an AFNetworking client by subclassing AFHTTPClient and setting base path

```
#define BaseURLString @"http://company.com/api/"

@implementation WineAPIClient

+(id)sharedInstance{
  static APIClient *__sharedInstance;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    __sharedInstance = [APIClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString]];
});
return __sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
 self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
if(self){
    [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
}

return self;
}

@end
```

This is how i am making request to the server:

```
[[APIClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"wines"
                               parameters:nil
                               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

                               }
                               failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Error fetching wines!");
                                        NSLog(@"%@",error);
                               }];
```

Now i have a class called LoginViewController which gets token number ones i loged in.

Now my question in how to set the token as an Authorization header in my AFHttpClinet class.

and make rest other  request using the Authorization header.

Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587453/afnetworking-2-authentication-with-afhttprequestoperation/19588186#19588186

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use methods of `AFNetworking`
`setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password:`

```
+(id)sharedInstance{
  static APIClient *__sharedInstance;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
  __sharedInstance = [APIClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString]];
  [__sharedInstance setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
  });
  return __sharedInstance;
}
```

**OR**

```
+(id)sharedInstance{
  static APIClient *__sharedInstance;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
  __sharedInstance = [APIClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString]];
  });
  return __sharedInstance;
}

- (void)updateAuthorizationHeaderUsername:(NSString *)username Password:(NSString *)password
{
    [self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:username password:password];
}

- (void)updateAuthorizationHeader:(NSString *)token
{
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"token" value:token];
}
```

Comment: I have to just set the token as AUthorizationHeader 

But The token is in different class...
and m saving that token in by Sqlite DB..

can we retirive the token nukmber from db and set in SetAuthorizationHeader method.

Comment: @Nilesh.S.Joshi you can do that. Add one methods for update credentials.

Comment: after login into the app i get the token number.....now let say i  have   search in the app ....and i need to call a search API for that....then i have to set that token number as an Authorization header for that request

Comment: If you want to send token through request header, then use method -setDefaultHeader:value:

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
[[APIClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"wines"
                           parameters:@{@"Authorization":TOKEN}
                           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

                           }
                           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Error fetching wines!");
                                    NSLog(@"%@",error);
                           }];
```

Where TOKEN is you token

Comment: Have you seen my above code.....if not then please do see that

I am not creating any NSMUtable request as such.

I am just using shared instance,which call the base url and thn m setting the path with parameters.

Can you please edit the above code......so that it will clear my doubt?

Comment: Ok sorry try this solution

Comment: I have to set that token as a Authorization header.....for the remaning request.......than how can i pass it as a parameters?

Comment: You can create property with NSDictinary and set you token there, and just call this property when you needed...